# typeorm react (expo SqlLite) native table always exist

Tags: react-native, typeorm

I have a problem with SQLite used with Typeorm, i use SDK 46.

Error message: [QueryFailedError: table “temporary_media_base” already exists (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE “temporary_media_base” (“id” varchar PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, “createdAt” datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime(’ now’)), “apiId” varchar, “updatedAt” datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime(‘now’)), “deletedAt” datetime, “label” varchar, “base64” varchar NOT NULL, “type” varchar NOT NULL, “noteId” varchar, CONSTRAINT “UQ_3aa2a1f345b42d934c4a87e7b00” UNIQUE (“apiId”), CONSTRAINT “FK_01c465d2205772621fd3986d004” FOREIGN KEY (“noteId”) REFERENCES “block_note” (“id”) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)]

my entity :

> import { Column, Entity, OneToMany } from “typeorm/browser”; import {
> BaseEntity } from “./base.entity”; import { EmploiTempsItemEntity }
> from “./emploi-temps-item”; import { SectionMatiereEntity } from
> “./section-matiere.entity”;
>
> @Entity(‘matiere’) export class MatiereEntity extends BaseEntity{
> @Column() label:string
>
> @Column() prof:string
>
> @OneToMany(
> type=>SectionMatiereEntity,
> (matiere)=>matiere.matiere,
> {
> nullable:true,
> cascade:true
> } ) sectionMatiere:MatiereEntity[]
>
> @OneToMany(
> type=>EmploiTempsItemEntity,
> (matiere)=>matiere.matiere,
> {
> nullable:true,
> cascade:true
> } ) emploiTemps:EmploiTempsItemEntity }

my package.json:

> { “name”: “matrive-v2”, “version”: “1.0.0”, “main”:
> “node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js”, “scripts”: { “start”: “expo start”,
> “android”: “expo start --android”, “ios”: “expo start --ios”, “web”:
> “expo start --web”, “typeorm”: “npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs
> --dataSource dataBase/data-source.ts” }, “dependencies”: { “@babel/preset-typescript”: “^7.18.6”, “@expo/vector-icons”:
> “^13.0.0”, “@react-native-community/blur”: “^4.2.0”,
> “@react-native-community/datetimepicker”: “^6.2.0”,
> “@react-native-community/masked-view”: “^0.1.11”,
> “@react-native-community/netinfo”: “^9.3.0”,
> “@react-navigation/drawer”: “^6.4.4”, “@react-navigation/native”:
> “^6.0.12”, “@react-navigation/native-stack”: “^6.8.0”,
> “@react-navigation/stack”: “^6.2.3”, “@shopify/flash-list”: “1.1.0”,
> “babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata”: “^0.3.2”,
> “class-transformer”: “^0.5.1”, “class-validator”: “^0.13.2”,
> “date-fns”: “^2.29.3”, “expo”: “~46.0.9”, “expo-dev-client”: “~1.2.1”,
> “expo-device”: “^4.3.0”, “expo-document-picker”: “^10.3.0”,
> “expo-file-system”: “^14.1.0”, “expo-image-picker”: “^13.3.1”,
> “expo-media-library”: “^14.2.0”, “expo-notifications”: “~0.16.1”,
> “expo-splash-screen”: “^0.16.2”, “expo-sqlite”: “^10.3.0”,
> “expo-status-bar”: “~1.4.0”, “expo-system-ui”: “^1.3.0”,
> “expo-updates”: “~0.14.6”, “install”: “^0.13.0”, “moment”: “^2.29.4”,
> “native-base”: “^3.4.13”, “npm”: “^8.19.2”, “npx”: “^10.2.2”, “react”:
> “18.0.0”, “react-class-validator”: “^1.4.0”, “react-dom”: “18.0.0”,
> “react-native”: “0.69.5”, “react-native-anchor-carousel”: “^4.0.1”,
> “react-native-drawer”: “^2.5.1”, “react-native-dropdown-picker”:
> “^5.4.2”, “react-native-fab”: “^1.0.18”, “react-native-flash-message”:
> “^0.3.1”, “react-native-floating-action”: “^1.22.0”,
> “react-native-gesture-handler”: “~2.5.0”,
> “react-native-get-random-values”: “^1.8.0”, “react-native-modal”:
> “^13.0.1”, “react-native-modalize”: “^2.1.1”,
> “react-native-multi-selectbox”: “^1.5.0”,
> “react-native-multi-selectbox-typescript”: “^0.1.2”,
> “react-native-pager-view”: “^5.4.24”, “react-native-portalize”:
> “^1.0.7”, “react-native-reanimated”: “~2.9.1”,
> “react-native-safe-area-context”: “4.3.1”, “react-native-screens”:
> “~3.15.0”, “react-native-svg”: “12.3.0”, “react-native-swiper”:
> “^1.6.0”, “react-native-tab-view”: “^3.1.1”, “react-native-web”:
> “~0.18.7”, “react-redux”: “^8.0.2”, “redux”: “^4.2.0”,
> “reflect-metadata”: “^0.1.13”, “typeorm”: “^0.3.9”, “uninstall”:
> “^0.0.0”, “uuid”: “^8.3.2” }, “devDependencies”: { “@babel/core”:
> “^7.12.9”, “@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from”: “^7.18.9”,
> “@types/node”: “^18.7.14”, “@types/react”: “~18.0.14”,
> “@types/react-native”: “~0.69.1”, “ts-node”: “^10.9.1”, “typescript”:
> “~4.3.5” }, “private”: true }

typeorm config:

> import * as SQLite from “expo-sqlite”;
>
> import { DataSourceOptions } from “typeorm/browser”;
>
> import { BloackNoteEntity } from “./entities/block-note.entity”;
>
> import { ConfigEntity } from “./entities/config.entity”;
>
> import { EmploiTempsItemEntity } from “./entities/emploi-temps-item”;
>
> import { EmploiTempsEntity } from “./entities/emploi-temps.entity”;
>
> import { EventEntity } from “./entities/envent.entity”;
>
> import { EventNotificationEntity } from
> “./entities/event-notifiaction.entity”;
>
> import { EventTypeEntity } from “./entities/event-type.entity”;
>
> import { MatiereEntity } from “./entities/matiere.entity”;
>
> import { MediaEntity } from “./entities/media.entity”;
>
> import { NoteEntity } from “./entities/note.entity”;
>
> import { SchoolYearEntity } from “./entities/school-year.entity”;
>
> import { SectionMatiereEntity } from
> “./entities/section-matiere.entity”;
>
> import { sectionEntity } from “./entities/section.entity”;
>
> import { TypeNoteEntity } from “./entities/type-note.entity”;
>
> import { UserEntity } from “./entities/user.enity”;
>
> const config:DataSourceOptions = {
>
> database: “mydatabase”,
>
> driver: SQLite,
>
> entities: [ConfigEntity,TypeNoteEntity,NoteEntity,
> UserEntity,BloackNoteEntity,EmploiTempsEntity,EmploiTempsItemEntity,
> SectionMatiereEntity,EventEntity,EventTypeEntity,EventNotificationEntity,
> MatiereEntity, sectionEntity,MediaEntity, SchoolYearEntity],
>
> type: “expo”,
>
> synchronize:true,
>
> entitySkipConstructor:true
>
> };
>
> export default config;